# Elastic Beanstalk - PHP / Force HTTPS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How do I redirect all traffic while using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with PHP from http to https? I have setup my Beanstalk to have a https port (all the certificate and stuff has been setup).

Comment: You want to push all pages to HTTPS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beanstalk sets up their load balancer to send `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers to your instance(s).

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] !== 'https') {
    // redirect to secure site
    header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Though, some will swear by not enabling HTTP at all, due to [SSL stripping](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) techniques used in MiTM attacks.

Having said that, you can mitigate SSL stripping by using [HSTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

Comment: Just one change it is supposed to be $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] instead of $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_PROTO']

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single instance elastic beanstalk environment, try this solution: [AWS Elasticbeanstalk single instance Force SSL Redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363051/aws-elasticbeanstalk-single-instance-force-ssl-redirect-loop)