# AWS Elasticbeanstalk single instance Force SSL Redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, ssl, amazon-web-services

I'm having issues by forcing ssl. I'm using codeigniter and deployed it in AWS single instance with elasticbeanstalk. My htaccess rules below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !/status https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But browser gets in a redirect loop. Whatever i tried didnt solve this problem.

Comment: Same problem here. The fact is, in the ssl.conf every call from port 443 is "proxyed" to port 80, so you never get https = on. Did you find out how to resolve that?

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment:

> in the ssl.conf every call from port 443 is "proxyed" to port 80, so you never get https = on.

I did some tests and I found out that the ProxyPass directive in ssl.conf does not simply redirect every request from port 443 to localhost:80, but basically repeats the request to Apache from scratch, through the port 80 (at least, that's what I understood).

I checked the value of **$_SERVER** and found out that **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR**, **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST** and **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER** are set during a **HTTPS** request (but they are **NOT** set during a **HTTP** request), meanwhile **SERVER_ADDR** and **REMOTE_ADDR** are set to **127.0.0.1** during a **HTTPS** request (but they are set to different values for **HTTP** requests).

I assume you can easily check if your request was plain HTTP with something like this (check the syntax, I'm rubbish with Apache):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER}   !^$
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SERVER_ADDR}   !^127\.0\.0\.1
```

**BEWARE: I couldn't find any reference in AWS documentation, it's just an empiric result... they can easily change this behavior!**

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem. Here is what worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR}   !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official way. Found in AWS docs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !ELB-HealthChecker
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Sources

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html

https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/php/https-redirect-php.config

Answer (score 0):

I believe (give your exception for /status) that you are using the "Load-balancing, Autoscaling Environment" which means you have an Elastic Load Balancer in the middle.

If you setup your environment with Elastic Load Balancing, than what may be happening is if the Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) is using (serving) secure content (HTTPS).

However, if the traffic between the ELB and the EC2 Instances is unsecure, your code will always detect an unsecure connection because the EC2 client is actually the ELB, not the end user (think of the ELB as a proxy).

*Side note, I'm not sure how the SERVER_NAME variable will work with an ELB in the middle.*

That said, if your intention was for a single-instance, non-load balanced environment, you can "turn off" the load balancer (possible since July 2013). (see ref #3)

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html
[Elastic Beanstalk without Elastic Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014046/elastic-beanstalk-without-loadbalancer)

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this causes a redirect loop for me.