# Https on Elastic Beanstalk - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an annoying issue with https on a wordpress website running on aws eb single instance.

I have the same website in a vps, https works fine, styles and css are served via https. Just to be sure (I've spent 2 days trying to figure out what's wrong) few minutes ago I deployed on eb a copy of the website - editing only the database settings.

So, the issue is that in eb if I go to https://mywebsite.com the page is "broken", styles and scripts are server through http.

In the vps if I go to https://mywebsite.com styles and scripts are https://mywebsite.com/styles/style.css, in eb styles and scripts are http://mywebsite.com/styles/style.css.

Why is this happening and how can I fix that?

I've tried edit the wp_options table and set siteurl and home to https://mywebsite.com (the same website in the vps has values set to http://mywebsite.com)

[AWS Elasticbeanstalk single instance Force SSL Redirect loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363051/aws-elasticbeanstalk-single-instance-force-ssl-redirect-loop)
htaccess (to force https or to force only http) is simply ignored, I've tried so many solutions but no one worked. The only solution that works for me is a php redirect to http after checking if the server variable http_x_forwarded_server is set

I've read that all the https connections - in eb single instance - through port 443 are "proxied" to port 80 (that could be the problem?)

So, any solutions? I don't want to force https in the website, so I don't want to install plugins that forces https, I just want that the website doesn't broke when navigating the website through https

Answer (score 1):

Just after adding the post, I've managed to solve this problem.

For future references, the solutions is to add this variable `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` and set it to `'on'`.

This is my code

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER'])) {
  $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

You can add it to index.php, or as I did, in the header.php of your theme (in this case be aware that if you change theme that code will not executed)